# Prevent from clicking through Sprite in 2D

Tags: unity, c#

I have this hierarchy (objects as sprites with colliders):

- object 1 as parent
- object 2 can be opened from object 1
- object 3 can be opened from object 2

The thing is I have many objects like this in my project that are nested and I want to prevent users from clicking through sprites. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Any other way than manually adjusting every objects Z position in the inspector?

[image]

Comment: There are many different ways to handle mouse input in Unity. Which one are you using? Are those canvas elements of spatial game objects?

Comment: I am using physics 2d raycast for my inputs. Not actually canvas elements but 2d sprites.